cannot setup a runtime server for a project in Eclipse
I had followed the "Student" Spring Boot project from spring.io.
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        super();
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/students")
    public String listStudents(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("students", studentService.getAllStudents());
        return "students";
    }

    @GetMapping("/students/new")
    public String createStudentForm(Model model) {
       Student student = new Student();
       model.addAttribute("student", student);
       return "create_student";
    }

    @PostMapping("/students")
    public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
       studentService.saveStudent(student);
       return "redirect/students";
    }

The problem is that I cannot associate the project with a new created runtime. I had consulted this post posr But I did not created a dynamic web project from Eclipse however I imported a project from initialzr with the dependencies. I have already re-installed Eclipse and tried to change the compiler 1.8 (17, 21) but I have never got access to target runtime when I click properties on the project. Any idea would be being accepted with many thanks
reinstall eclipse (2024)

Could you include a URL to this project you're following? Spring Boot applications are Java Applications, you wouldn't need a separate server runtime.
